# Add class to image in view

Tags: views, theming

Is there a way to add a specific class to the img tag in a view? I'd prefer to use a template to perform it. I can see how I can change what classes the image is wrapped in, but I don't see a way to edit the classes of the img tag itself.

I see there's a way to edit the image field using **views-view-field--field-image.tpl.php** however the only variable I can see that is available is $output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `.myclass img { your code goes here }` is not good enough and you must have the class inside the img tag, then:

1) Download and enable the [Image URL Formater Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter)

2) On your view's picture field, select url as format.

3)

**Option A)** In the rewrite results field type `<img src="[field_image]" class="yay-we-did-it">`

**Option B)** if you want to use the .tpl.php file, put this inside it.

`<img src='<?php print $fields["field_image"]->content; ?>' class='yay-we-did-it'>`

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a tpl answer.